# TikZ: Draw a unit vector

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a two point `p1` and `p2`:

```
  \node (p1) at (-1,-2) [point, label = {left:$P_1$}]{};
  \node (p2) at (3, 4) [point, label = {below:$P_2$}]{};
```

How to draw a unit vector beginning at the point `p1` and directed to a point `p2` using only the variables `p1` and `p2`?

Comment: By normalizing it.

Comment: Don't use `\node` to define `\coordinate`...

Answer (score 6):

You can use the calc library syntax with units. If you omit the unit it is understood as the full path percentage. Otherwise, depending on the unit that distance is traveled.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[point/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=2pt}]
\node[point, label = {left:$P_1$}] (p1) at (-1,-2) {}; 
\node[point, label = {below:$P_2$}] (p2) at (3, 4) {};

\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {,mm,cm,in}{
\draw[opacity=1/\xi,line width=\xi pt] (p1) -- ($(p1)!1\x!(p2)$);% 1,1mm,1cm,1in respectively
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `p1` is not `p1.center`...

Comment: Ok, but how to get distance between points p1 and p2?

Comment: @user67420 Search for `veclen` in `pgfmanual`.

Comment: @user67420 You want a unit vector why do you need the distance? You just need to specify the `1<unit>`

Comment: @PaulGaborit True, but it is for example. You just need either `(p2)` for the finish or `($(p1)!0!(p2)$)` for the start to make things equal for the full path.

Answer (score 3):

This draws the lines by a fraction of the distance between `p1` and `p1`. For example `20%` of the distance between `p1` and `p2`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[point/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=2pt}]
\node[coordinate, label = {left:$P_1$}] (p1) at (-1,-2){};
\node[coordinate, label = {below right:$P_2$}] (p2) at (3, 4){};
\node[point] at (p1){};
\node[point] at (p2){};

\draw  let
\p1 = ($ (p2) - (p1) $),
\n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
in
(p1) -- ($(p1)!0.2*\n1!(p2)$)node[pos=1,right] {\pgfmathparse{0.2*\n1}\pgfmathresult};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `0.2*\n1` is equivalent to `0.2` in this context.